# Cocos2d-x error while compiling LOCAL_SRC_FILES points to a missing file (and folder) Windows

Tags: android, android-ndk, cocos2d-android

Good evening.

I'm stuck trying to compile a HelloWorld using the cocos2d-x.
I used the following commands:

- `cocos compile -p android --android-studio`
- `cocos compile -p android --android-studio`
- `cocos compile -p android`

And I always had the same answer

```
Android NDK: ERROR:C:\Users\santi_000\Desktop\Android\cocos2d\HelloWorld\proj.android\../cocos2d/external/freetype2/prebuilt/android/Android.mk:cocos_freetype2_static: LOCAL_SRC_FILES points to the missing file
Android NDK: Check que C:/Users/santi_000/Desktop/Android/cocos2d/HelloWorld/proj.android/../cocos2d/external/freetype2/prebuilt/android/arm64-v8a/libfreetype.a exists or que its path is correct
make: Entering directory `C: /Users/santi_000/Desktop/Android/cocos2d/HelloWorld/proj.android '
C: / Users / santi_000 / AppData / Local / Android / sdk / ndk-bundle / build //../ build / core / prebuilt-library.mk: 45: *** Android NDK: Aborting. Stop.
make: Leaving directory `C: /Users/santi_000/Desktop/Android/cocos2d/HelloWorld/proj.android '
Error running command, return code: 2.
```

I found some pages here in StackOverFlow however none of them helped me. I'm using Windows. I realized I do not even have the arm64-V8A folder, what do I do? Where I can copy it, or how can I generate it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following worked for me

```
cocos compile --android-studio --target android-22 
    --ap android-22 --ndk-mode debug --ndk-toolchain arm-linux-androideabi-4.9 
    --platform android --app-abi armeabi --src C:\cocos2d-x\tests\cpp-tests
```

You will need to replace the `--ndk-toolchain` to the proper one that comes with your NDK installation. Check in the toolchains folder inside NDK_ROOT.

The most important one that actually got it working was `--app-abi armeabi` as that is what was the toolchain used.

[Edit]
If you actually check `cocos compile -h` you will see that `--app-abi` mentions `armeabi` as the default. But that is not the case. It is picking up `arm64` as the default.

Comment: Also changing the gradle version in `cocos2d-x\tests\cpp-tests\proj.android-studio\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties` to 2.10 instead of 2.4 worked inside Android Studio.

Comment: `--app-abi armeabi` worked for me. There is an `armeabi` directory inside `cocos2d/external/freetype2/prebuilt/android`, but no `arm64` directory.

Comment: Thank. You. Been trying for hours. Logged in to up vote.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the commands to compile the android project starts with `cocos` not `coconuts`.

> cocos compile -p android --android-studio

or

> cocos compile -p android

Now, for the above error, it seems, you haven't set `NDK_HOME` path in environment variable.
You can set it manually or goto your cocos2d-x library folder from terminal and run

```
./setup.py
```

It will do the rest.

Comment: He had set the NDK_HOME, it's using the ndk-bundle directory from Android Studio (as you can see in the path). I've run into the same errors in OSX. Seems that cocos2d-x isn't fully compatible with the latest NDK (also a manual download from http://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/index.html was not working). I saw it, because the build tool was looking for RELEASE.TXT which was missing in both cases.